# How to get the value of "_index" used in gazebo::physics::Joint Class

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In class "Joint",lots of  Public Member Functions need the "index" as a Parameter.How can I get its value?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2947/how-to-get-the-value-of-%22_index%22--used-in-gazebo::physics::joint-class/) by [Sway](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/359/sway/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Because the joint connects two links, one being the child and the other the parent, this can be (0, 1), where **index = 0** it is the **child** link and **index = 1** it is the **parent** link.

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0